# Mac Pro Wired keyboard sending garbage

Tags: keyboard, hardware, hardware-recommendation

Mac Pro 2010.  Keyboard in use since beginning.
No problems for a decade.

I've had keyboard failures before, but usually they fall into the following categories:

- Doesn't work at all.
- One key doesn't work.
- One key sticks.

Recently it's been truly weird.  All of this started between one login and another.

- Half the keys send nothing.
- Some of the keys send 189'  Yes.  3 digits and a single quote.
- Both g and h send the pair dh.
- 3 sends 20
- One time when I hit l(ell) I got L without hitting the shift key.  Unable to get that event to happen again.

I used another keyboard.  No problem.
I checked keyboard and accessibility preferences.  Vanilla.

Is it just new keyboard time?  Current keyboard is aluminum base, separate number pad, movement keys, usb port on each end.  User likes this keyboard. Would like to get an identical replacement.

Additions in response to comment:

- Yes.  Did the plug/unplug/different ports.  That one keyboard worked but the other didn't indicates that the port is ok.
- Also early on tried zapping the pram figuring it was some device issue.

Comment: If  you changed keyboards and it worked as it  should, then  yes  it's  new  keyboard time. I suspect that the ROM that  contains the  map  of  scan codes is  corrupted since it's  sending utter  garage.

Comment: I assume that unplugging it and re-plugging it in did not fix the problem. Is it plugged directly into computer or via a hub/extension/etc? Did you try a different USB port? Did you go to System Preferences » Keyboard » Change Keyboard Type… and make sure it is set properly? While there, check "Input Sources" and see if it is set to the correct region. Do you have another Mac that you can use with this keyboard, to see if it acts incorrectly there as well? I have one of those keyboards (but without the number pad) and don't know if anyone makes anything like that any more.

Comment: The good news is, when Apple first stopped making them eBay prices went ballistic - up to $£€ 140 [same price as the newer wireless] for what was 40 the week before. They have now sensibly dropped back to 25 or 30 even for a brand new one. tbh I've never known one fail without a spill, usually after 8 or so years the letters wear off ;) Best keyboards Apple ever made, imho.

Comment: *usually after 8 or so years the letters wear off*  Yes indeed, but after 11 years my fingers know where all the keys are, so it would be in-keeping with Apple's somewhat minimalist design if it were a feature - get rid of the letters when the user no longer needs them !

Comment: @Tetsujin is right: _best keyboards Apple ever made._ I have five of them in the garage, lined up and waiting for the one on my desk to fail.

Comment: I have one letter-less spare, from my first '08 Mac Pro, 3 others still in daily use on '09 & '10 Macs. The only one that ever died was unfortunately drowned in coffee. They are really not [easily] repairable, as they're glued not screwed.